# Cannot access to Kubernetes Ingress (Istio) on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, istio, gke-networking

I set up Istio (Kubernetes Ingress mode, NOT Istio Gateway) on GKE. However, I cannot access from outside using curl

```
kubectl get svc -n istio-system | grep ingressgateway
```

> istio-ingressgateway LoadBalancer 10.48.11.240 35.222.111.100
> 15020:30115/TCP,80:31420/TCP,443:32019/TCP,31400:31267/TCP,15029:30180/TCP,15030:31055/TCP,15031:32226/TCP,15032:30437/TCP,15443:31792/TCP
> 41h

```
curl 35.222.111.100
```

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to 35.222.111.100 port 80: Connection
> refused

This is the config of Ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: istio
  name: ingress
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: in-keycloak
                port:
                  number: 8080
```

This is the config of the Service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: in-keycloak
  labels:
    app: keycloak
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: keycloak
  type: ClusterIP
```

**If I use the same config for Docker Desktop on local machine (MacOS), it works fine.**

Comment: Please edit your question by adding formatted text instead of screenshots.

Comment: Thank you, I have just updated

Comment: How exactly did you install your Istio? With `istioctl`, Istio Operator, an addon?

Comment: On GKE, I just enabled it.
On my local machine, I installed it using instructions from this: https://istio.io/v1.6/docs/setup/getting-started/

Comment: Hey @CaoMinhVu, Is your GKE cluster public or private? Could you please clarify if this setup does work with ingress gateway instead of ingress?

Comment: Hi Jakub, it is a private cluster. It works with ingress gateway mode, therefore, it is not a problem with my project. But I am curious with the Kubernetes Ingress mode

Comment: I've tested this [ingress](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/kubernetes-ingress/#configuring-ingress-using-an-ingress-resource) on public GKE and it worked out of the box. As for the private GKE cluster, have you opened the port 15017 as mentioned in [documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/platform-setup/gke/)? Also I think your ingress resource is not configured properly, [there](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/kubernetes-ingress/#specifying-ingressclass) is an example on how it should be configured. Could you please try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 things that must be met on GKE to make it work with istio on private cluster.

1.To make istio work on GKE you should follow these [instructions](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/platform-setup/gke/) to prepare a GKE cluster for Istio. It also inclused to open a 15017 port so istio could work.

```
For private GKE clusters

An automatically created firewall rule does not open port 15017. This is needed by the Pilot discovery validation webhook.

To review this firewall rule for master access:

$ gcloud compute firewall-rules list --filter="name~gke-${CLUSTER_NAME}-[0-9a-z]*-master"

To replace the existing rule and allow master access:

$ gcloud compute firewall-rules update <firewall-rule-name> --allow tcp:10250,tcp:443,tcp:15017
```

2.Comparing to istio documentation I would say your ingress is not properly configured, below you can find an ingress resource from the [documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/kubernetes-ingress/#specifying-ingressclass) you might try to use instead:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: IngressClass
metadata:
  name: istio
spec:
  controller: istio.io/ingress-controller
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
spec:
  ingressClassName: istio
  rules:
  - host: httpbin.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          serviceName: httpbin
          servicePort: 8000
```